# HTTPKerberosAuth does not work when I try to specify the principal manually

Tags: python, authentication, python-requests, authorization, kerberos

I am running Python (2.7.*) code relying

```
from requests_kerberos import HTTPKerberosAuth
```

I am attempting to make a request against a Windows Authentication secured IIS server. Windows Authentication uses the domain controller to authenticate requests first using Kerberos then NTLM should Kerberos fail.

The code is running on a Linux machine where I am logged in as a domain user (e.g matt@dopeafcompany.com)

If I run

```
AUTH = HTTPKerberosAuth(mutual_authentication=REQUIRED, force_preemptive=True)
```

There is no issue - all works correctly.

However, if I try to run

```
AUTH = HTTPKerberosAuth(mutual_authentication=REQUIRED,
       force_preemptive=True, principal='bob@dopeafcompany.com:bobspw')
```

Then I get an authorized response.

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: What's the error you're getting? From the code you provided, there would be a syntax error, but that might just be a transcription error.

Comment: Yes, transcription error - I get a 401.1 from the web server - unauthorized.